# Web API controller in subfolder not being found with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller in this folder structure:

```
Site
-Controllers
--API
---EventsController.cs
```

The EventsController.cs contains this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    [Route("event")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

The WebApiConfig.cs contains this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I run the site from Visual Studio and try to access http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/event I see nothing but this error:

```
<Error>
  <Message>
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/event'.
  </Message>
  <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'event'.
  </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

If I comment out the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute line to make WebApiConfig.cs as the following, the URL above works:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //  name: "DefaultApi",
    //  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    //  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    //);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is it that causes the attribute routing to fail when the DefaultApi route is configured? I have tried placing it before/after the config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); and neither works.

As an aside, I have manually built up this project while reading the following article, which has the same structure of MVC/Web API project and which does work. I just can't figure out what I've done differently.

http://www.codemag.com/Article/1605081

Comment: It's not immediately obvious, but something that does stick out is your `EventsController` it looks like it inherits an Mvc controller and not an Api one.  Also, What is the intent of `EventsController`? Is it an Mvc controller returning a view but with an /api/ route? My guess is the attribute routing is getting muddled because it's on an Mvc controller.

Comment: Thank you! Just 3 characters out of place and it all goes cray cray!

Comment: No problem, glad it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@phil-cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746674/phil-cooper) the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736140/web-api-controller-in-subfolder-not-being-found-with-attribute-routing#comment70667964_41736140) was to inherit the correct base class in the api controller.

Comment: So how how did you inherit correct base class. I’m having the same issue but not sure which 3 characters you removed to fix this. How did you fix it?

Comment: Ah, by "correct" I mean the EventsController from the Api namespace, not the Mvc namespace. I will try to update my posted answer with the correct line later, but I also haven't posted the `using` statements in the question, either. (I see that a lot here.) In short, the answer is to inherit from this namespace: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller?view=aspnetcore-2.2